# Change what text editor the "Open this file in GitHub for Mac" link uses

Tags: github, github-for-mac

When I click this link it opens up the file in Xcode. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any way to change this. I would like it to open in Sublime or Atom. I've checked the GitHub for Mac preferences menu but there is nothing there related to your default editor. I've tried changing my default git editor but that doesn't work either. How do I set the editor GitHub for Mac uses?

[image]

Comment: Did you check your `git config --global core.editor` value? (the *global* config)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Github for Mac uses the same application that finder would use if you double clicked on the file. You can follow these instructions to change the default application for a given file type http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-change-the-default-application-to-open-files--mac-51413.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the accepted answer does not works anymore.

I just created simple chrome extension which allows to automatically replace `github-mac` links to any other existing url provider with template set by user in the options: https://github.com/extempl/github-mac-replacer.

Comment: Interesting. +1. I wasn't aware of this regression.

Comment: Actually, Github-Mac uses `reveal in finder` for this action. So it is still possible to use it without any modification.

But it thinks a bit long, launches github-mac app, and requires project to be added into the app.

As long as I do not use github client, this is not very handy.

Comment: OK. I get it now.